# How to remove remembered autocomplete items in Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, autocomplete

I love the way the browser remember the text I entered into a form field - especially when I'm a developer. It saves lots of my typing time.

Though, sometimes there are unwanted remembered items and need to be removed. I don't know how to do that in Firefox and Chrome. Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With both Chrome and Firefox you can just highlight the term you want to delete and hit the delete button.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Firefox, but in Chrome, I've removed choices from the auto-fill drop-down by highlighting an unwanted choice by hovering the cursor over it and pressing [Shift+Delete].

Answer (score 0):

As per suggestion from [this comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=771952#c3):

1. Go to: `chrome://settings/autofill`

   Alternatively go to *Settings* (*Advanced*) and Find *Autofill settings* (under *Passwords and forms section*).
2. Then select *Manage Autofill* settings.
3. In the dialog, select the entry which you'd like to remove.

See: [How to clear unwanted autofill entries in Google Chrome](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3145489/browsers/how-to-clear-unwanted-autofill-entries-in-google-chrome.html).